# Given a dictionary of numbers, determine which sets contain unique values (i.e. numbers that do not belong to any of the other sets)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, unique

Looking for the most efficient way to solve this using Objective-C (and Swift as a second preference).

You have a NSDictionary containing the below sets for example.

```
NSDictionary dict = @{ 
   { @"foo", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] },
   { @"bar", [NSNumber numberWithInt:10] },
   { @"baz", [NSNumber numberWithInt:11] },
   { @"boz", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] }, 
};
```

I should receive a list containing values (1, 10, 11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the values (as an array, `[dict allValues]`) and coerce to an NSSet (`initWithArray:`).

You can always coerce back to an array if you really do want an array; but I find in general that often people *think* they need an array when what they really needed was a set in the first place.

Comment: Hey, I'm not even finished editing my answer yet. :)

Comment: Hehe, I already was out for this solution, I was practicing mainly at the moment and you got it right away :-)

Comment: Okay, _now_ I'm finished. :)))

Comment: "people *think* they need an array when what they really needed was a set in the first place"... True, true.